# Is there a good practice in choosing a key for QMap/map

Tags: c++, qt, dictionary, qmap

I need to use `QMap<QTcpSocket*, QString>` just to keep a name of every connection.

I was told that using a complex object like QTcpSocket as a key is not ideal since the way map compares key, it could think there is a duplicate while it isn't.

So I would be apparently be better to use `QMap<QString, QTcpSocket*>` instead.

I was not able to find "good practice" information on it.
Is there any ground to this? Are some objects more/less recommended than others to use as keys?

Comment: If you use pointers to objects as keys, it is not possible to have duplicates, because it is impossible to have two different objects with the same address. So `QMap<QTcpSocket*, QString>` looks good to me.

Comment: Would it be different if it was not a pointer?

Comment: If it is not a pointer, QMap will need to compare two QTcpSockets. You will need to implement your own `operator<` for them.

Answer (score 3):

As @vahancho mentioned, using a pointer to the object in this case is not a problem.

However, as you're wanting to keep a name of each connection, consider that QTcpSocket is a QObject.

With this in mind, you can call the function **setObjectName( const QString & name)** to name the object and the function **objectName()** to retrieve it, as described in the [documentation for QObject](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qobject.html#objectName-prop).